# Undefined control sequence: \undefinedpagestyle at \end{macrocode}

Tags: environments, fancyhdr, dtx

The full source can be found [here](https://github.com/vermiculus/brdcrmbs/blob/9a2120c5e4f9fe97e8cd514f48329213283761f3/brdcrmbs.dtx#L153) (static link), but here is the relevant bit:

```
...
%    \begin{macrocode}
%<*package>
%    \end{macrocode}
% \begin{macro}{\BCSet}
% And stuff
%    \begin{macrocode}
\NewDocumentCommand{\BCSet}{m}
 {
  \keys_set:n { #1 }
 }
%    \end{macrocode} %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% ERROR HERE %%%%%%%%%%
% \end{macro}
%\begin{macro}{\examplemacro}
%\changes{v1.0}{2009/10/06}{Some change from the previous version}
%    \begin{macrocode}
\newcommand*\examplemacro[2][]{%
  Some code here, probably
}
%    \end{macrocode}
%\end{macro} 
%    \begin{macrocode}


\ExplSyntaxOn
...
```

As for a MWE, I'm not sure that DTX files can get much more minimal than the one I have right now; I've only added a short expository section and a macro def.
I've tried to follow the example exactly since I'm still new to the `dtx` format.  I don't know why it's giving me the following error:

> ```
> ERROR: Undefined control sequence.
>
> --- TeX said ---
> <argument> \undefinedpagestyle 
>
> l.153 %    \end{macrocode}
>
> --- HELP ---
> TeX encountered an unknown command name. You probably misspelled the
> name. If this message occurs when a LaTeX command is being processed,
> the command is probably in the wrong place---for example, the error
> can be produced by an \item command that's not inside a list-making
> environment. The error can also be caused by a missing \documentclass
> command.
> ```

I believe it's a problem somehow with `fancyhdr`, since that is where I recognize the command from, but I can't be certain.  Again, the full source at the time of writing can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/vermiculus/brdcrmbs/blob/9a2120c5e4f9fe97e8cd514f48329213283761f3/brdcrmbs.dtx#L153).

Comment: The error happens when there is an instruction such as `\pagestyle{foo}`, where `foo` is not a defined style.

Comment: @egreg That fixed the problem, but why does dtx-compilation fail when a style file wouldn't work?  Is this a 'feature' and, more importantly, can I turn it off?

Comment: Any LaTeX compilation would fail with the same error if a pagestyle that's requested is undefined.

Comment: Because I'm inputting `\jobname.sty`... gr.  Thanks @egreg!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The document use a `breadcrumb` page style without defining it. This just makes it the same as page style `plain`.

```
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\makeatletter
\let\ps@breadcrumb\ps@plain
\makeatother
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{\jobname}
\usepackage[numbered]{hypdoc}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\EnableCrossrefs
\CodelineIndex
\RecordChanges
\begin{document}
  \DocInput{\jobname.dtx}
\end{document}
```

It is essentially unrelated to `dtx` processing. It is just that this document loads the generated package.

Answer (score 0):

At @egreg's prodding, I looked into the error more and discovered that, while I didn't realize it, I was including my own package into the document via `\usepackage{\jobname.sty}`.  This caused - as I put it - a feature that checked my own package for errors.  I did indeed have an error, but it did not throw where I thought it would have; I was using the undefined page-style `breadcrumb` in my document.