# Undefined Control Sequence after removing \thesisdraft

Tags: chapters, undefined

I am writing my master's thesis using the LaTeX template provided by my university. I have also created separate tex files for each chapter and am including them from the main `thesis.tex` file. On it, there was a line `%\thesisdraft` which added timestamps at the top of each page. After I removed the line, I get an error on the `\chapter{chapter title}` line of my chapter1.tex file.

This is how the error message looks like: 
[image: c]

This is the [link](https://www.overleaf.com/3114921533pcgyvtnmtqpd) to the (editable) copy of the template that I am using. I have commented the `\thesisdraft` line and am getting an error here too.

Comment: If you look in the `.log` file and find the error message, it will tell you which macro/control sequence caused the error. It will be the last one on the first line of the error message. If that doesn't help you identify the problem, I think you need to give us more information, in the form of a minimal working example (see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/), i.e. a small self-contained document that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I have updated my post with an image of the error message. Does it help?

Comment: Assuming Overleaf does something sensible with the error, the `\undefinedpagestyle` means (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123337) that your document uses a pagestyle without having first defined it. Beyond that I can't really add anything.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I have also added a link to the copy of the template where you can make edits. Is there any way you can fix the error?

Comment: Don't have time to look at it right now.

Comment: I understand. Kindly have a look at it whenever you get the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tcdthesis.sty` uses the `fancy` pagestyle, but neither it nor `thesis.tex` actually loads the `fancyhdr` package, which defines a pagestyle by that name. They don't define a `fancy` pagestyle anywhere else either.

Add

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
```

before `\begin{document}`.

Comment: That has removed the errors and now I also see the section title and the chapter title on the header of each page like [this](https://imgur.com/kvl1A1U). I don't know if that's part of the template or is an unintended side effect.

Comment: @NeerajAthalye It's part of the `fancy` pagestyle defined by the `fancyhdr` package. If that is the pagestyle that the template author(s) intended to use, then yes, it's part of the template. But ask whoever made the template if you want to know for sure.